# Truecrypt Encryption stops encryption at 96% complete

Tags: windows, freeze, truecrypt

Initially I successfully completed a whole disk encryption of my Window 7 32 bit HP laptop with Truecrypt.  Subsequently, this same laptop was knocked off a table while CC Cleaner was running.  On reboot I ran into many issues and had to go back to an earlier system version using a System Restore.  After the laptop was stable, I also fully decrypted the drive.  I have used a couple of tools to clean up the machine and fix registry issues after the decryption.

The PC is now running great, booting cleanly, and running/processing quickly.

I an now attempting to re-encrypt this same hard drive with Truecrypt.  I disconnect all external items such as printers, phone chargers, and turn off Network/Internet access, and stop my antivirus software and end all un-needed processes, such as Bonjour, iTunesHelper.exe, etc.

Truecrypt now quickly encrypts the drive until around 96% of the drive is encrypted, then stops working, and freezes the balance of the laptop.

I have to unplug the machine and pull the battery to restart the machine.

I would appreciate any advice on what may be going on that is keeping me from fully encrypting my drive.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The hard drive is probably failing or damaged.  Have you tried another hard drive in the laptop? Does the drive stop at 96% or run really slow because it's having a hard time encrypting the data?

Comment: It has actually done this twice.  I ran a check disk and all appears well.  Is there another tool or utility you would recommend to check the drive?

Comment: @DaveW Spinrite is a good product to try. http://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm